# Crear dos claves foraneas Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Necesito generar por consola un modelo con dos claves foraneas. Es correcta esta manera?

```
rails generate scaffold Turnos fecha:date hora:time prestador:references afiliado:references
```

Comment: Si los modelos `prestador` y `afiliado` existen, entonces si, deberían funcionar.

Comment: Si, de esa manera me funciono bien. Muchas gracias